# Unable to create Provisioning Profile for iOS App Development (no certificates available)

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I am trying to build my first iOS app (I just successfully published an Android app to Google Play, so I'm *somewhat* familiar with the general process of building, codesigning, publishing and submitting for review).

I have created an Apple Developer account, and have set up an "App" resource inside the **App Store Connect** console.

I am now trying to create a **Provisioning Profile**, and am seeing something quite unexpected. I've successfully created a **Certificate** already as you can see here:

[image]

Now when I go back to the main screen, you'll see I don't have any Profiles setup yet, so I click on `Generate a profile`:

[image]

Which brings me to this screen:

[image]

I select `iOS App Development` and click `Continue`, which brings me to this screen:

[image]

I select my App ID and click `Continue`, which brings me to this screen:

[image]

**No certificates available?!?!** Why is it not allowing me to select the certificate listed on the first screen?

I have gone through the process of creating a certificate via that `Create Certificate` button (which is how I got the certificate listed on that other page!).

Any ideas as to why its not finding my Certificate? Is this a configuration issue, a bug in the Developer console or a case for a support request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up correctly until the third step. It should be in the `Distribution` section. You created a distribution certificate type, but you selected a development provisioning.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh OK, thank you @son (+1). So is "Distribution" considered "Production" and "Development" dev/non-prod?

Comment: Yeah, the Development Provisioning is used to produce and install apps in the development mode only.

Comment: Super quick followup question @son, if you don't mind: I have generated and downloaded the profile, but now how do I attach/connect it to my project? When I go to build my project I get the following error: `No profiles for 'com.example.myapp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.example.myapp'.`

Comment: That's exactly what I said above, you're missing development certificate & provisioning too. You just need to create both, production for AppStore and development for debug mode. Or simply create a development certificate and tick `Automatically manage signing` then Xcode will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks @son but I still feel like I'm missing something big here. What is the point of downloading the profile if I don't need to do anything with it, locally? I feel like I'm supposed to place or install it somewhere on my local machine, likely in the project somewhere, no?

Comment: Provisioning can be configured manually in Xcode -> Build setting, you can try it yourself after downloading it. You're right about `something` needs to be saved on your local machine. It's on KeyChain. You can check it by opening KeyChain -> My Certificates. You will see these dev/prod certificates that were created before there.

Comment: Ahhhh...@son what if I was trying to get this to build and auto-codesign as part of a CI/CD pipeline (specifically a GitHub action)? What would the `something` look like in that scenario? In other words, lets pretend I can store the profile on, say, AWS S3, and then fetch it from inside a GitHub action. What would that action need to do with the fetched profile to make it available to the local build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257190/discussion-between-son-and-hotmeatballsoup).